# Lie Groups and Matrices

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

I vaguely remember (maybe I am making this up) this. Is there some sort of result about Lie groups (of a certain class) which classifies them as matrix Lie groups? In other words, given a Lie group G, there exists an isomorphism from G into a matrix Lie group? If G admits a faithful representation, then most certainly...

Comment: The finite dimensional Lie algebras are classified via [Ado's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ado%27s_theorem).  I am not aware of the analogous theorem for Lie groups.

Comment: There are certainly Lie groups, however, that can't be realized as matrices with complex entries.

Comment: See also [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/64195/when-is-a-finite-dimensional-real-or-complex-lie-group-not-a-matrix-group?rq=1) and [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/62624/complex-lie-group-without-faithful-real-representations).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Ado's theorem is not a classification theorem. It says that every finite-dimensional Lie algebra is a Lie algebra of matrices, but it doesn't tell you how many of these there are or how to tell them apart. I remember being told that the classification of nilpotent Lie algebras is wild starting in dimension $7$ or so.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan right; I wasn't being careful with my words there, my mistake

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: the classification of nilpotent (complex) Lie algebras is known up to dim 7, up to dim 6 it's finite and in dim 7 there are infinite families but it's a full classification. However I don't think it's wild in dimension 8, it's just that there is no written classification yet (it would involve a few families with several parameters and it would most likely be quite messy... it's quite bad when there are several written classifications and one doesn't know how to pass from one to another, let alone when there are some flaws...).

Comment: Hmm. Maybe it was the classification of solvable Lie algebras?

Answer (score 4):

As Robert Israel says, this is exactly the question of which Lie groups $G$ admit a faithful finite-dimensional representation. Some comments:

- An easy sufficient condition is that $G$ is connected and has trivial center, in which case its [adjoint representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation) is faithful.
- Another sufficient condition is that $G$ is compact; this is nontrivial and is a corollary of the [Peter-Weyl theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter%E2%80%93Weyl_theorem).
- [Ado's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ado%27s_theorem) asserts that every finite-dimensional Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ has a faithful finite-dimensional representation. It follows that every simply connected Lie group $G$ admits a finite-dimensional representation whose kernel is a discrete subgroup of its center.
- An example of a Lie group which does not admit a faithful finite-dimensional representation is $G = \widetilde{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$, the universal cover of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$. This is because $G$ has the same finite-dimensional representation theory as its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{R})$, which in turn has the same finite-dimensional representation theory as $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$. So every finite-dimensional representation of $G$ factors through $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is exactly the question of which Lie groups admit a faithful representation.  Compactness is a sufficient condition.

Comment: See also the article by [Moskowitz](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01187063#page-1), in addition to the discussions on MO.

Comment: Why is compactness a sufficient condition for admitting faithful representations? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @Andy: check out "Peter-Weyl theorem"